# How is ADHD different to internet/social media/information addiction?

Tags: clinical-psychology, addiction, adhd

One of the concerns about ADHD diagnosis is how is it not just inattentiveness due to the modern hazard of instant gratification via social media/the internet.

[Here's a post of a wrote on the subject.](https://eyesofablacksheep.wordpress.com/2015/06/24/initial-thoughts-about-an-adhd-diagnosis/)

I had a quick look at [the Wikipedia article on ADHD controversies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_deficit_hyperactivity_disorder_controversies), but this arguement doesn't actually appear. Instead it's more about methods of diagnosis, and whether ADHD like symptoms are simply personality traits.

Can you answer:

- Is the possible issue of inattention due to ADHD and inattention due to social media addiction an issue in pyschiatric/medical circles?
- How are they distingushed?

Comment: Hey dwjohnston, just removed some personal references like I did from your other question. Feel free to edit the question some more.

Comment: @Seanny123 Is there a reason that personal references are a bad thing?

Comment: When you use personal references your question starts looking like a self-help question which is off topic for this site

Comment: Could it not be interpreted as context for why someone would want to know?

Comment: It could give context, however I would argue (and maybe you want to check with a moderator on this), that it isn't a *useful* context as it distracts from the theoretical core of the question. For further information on what a self-help question is and why it's discouraged, [check out this meta post](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/503/4397)

Comment: Two years later, I have a bit more advice if you want to make this question more answerable. Could you clarify why you linked to that blog post, maybe with an excerpt? Could you specify what part of the process of ADHD diagnosis could be confused for Internet addiction and why you think they should be distinct?